# How to do a binary if statement in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set with a column of letters, followed by another column of ones and zeroes. I want to total the amount of "ones" for each letter, but am unsure how to do so in an effective way.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by the first column ('col1') and then get the `sum` of 'col2'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(col1) %>%
   summarise(Total = sum(col2))
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Total = sum(col2)), col1]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
rowsum(df1$col2, df1$col1)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other base R solutions

```
> tapply(df$col2, df$col1, sum)
a b c 
1 1 2 

> xtabs(col2~col1,df)
col1
a b c 
1 1 2
```

**Dummy Data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), col2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

> df
   col1 col2
1     a    0
2     c    0
3     a    0
4     b    0
5     a    1
6     c    1
7     c    1
8     b    1
9     b    0
10    c    0
```